# Reading text in grouped objects

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I made a presentation (with PowerPoint 2016 in Windows 10) on which there are text attached to the images.

I know VBA (not thoroughly) for Word or Excel but I'm new to PP. But PowerPoint grammar confuses me (it will also be for my age). I want to extract all the title and text of all the slides and about this I create the following program which works fine but doesn't let me know the text on grouped objects. Where am I wrong?

```vb
Sub RiepilogaConWord()
  Dim applWord As Word.Application
  Dim docWord As Word.Document
  Dim paraWord As Word.Paragraph
  Dim oSh As Shape
  Dim oSL As Slide
    
  Set applWord = New Word.Application
  applWord.Visible = True
  applWord.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
  Set docWord = applWord.Documents.Add
  docWord.ShowSpellingErrors = False
  applWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="RIEPILOGO AL " & Format(Date, "dd/mm/YYYY") & " alle ore " & Format(Time, "hh:mm")
  docWord.Paragraphs.Add
  Set paraWord = docWord.Paragraphs(docWord.Paragraphs.Count)
  paraWord.Range.InsertAfter "Totale diapositive " & Presentations(1).Slides.Count
  docWord.Paragraphs.Add
    
  For Each oSL In ActivePresentation.Slides
    paraWord.Range.InsertAfter oSL.SlideIndex
    docWord.Paragraphs.Add
    Dim g As Integer
    For Each oSh In oSL.Shapes
      Select Case oSh.Type
        Case Is = msoGroup
          On Error Resume Next
          oSh.Ungroup.Group , msoTextBox
          For g = 1 To oSh.GroupItems.Count
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
              paraWord.Range.InsertAfter oSh.Name & ":= " & oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                        
            End If
          Next g
          On Error GoTo errorhandler
        Case Else
          With oSh
            If .HasTextFrame Then
              If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                paraWord.Range.InsertAfter oSh.Name & ":= " & .TextFrame.TextRange
                          
              End If
            End If
          End With
       
      End Select
    Next
  Next   

  docWord.SaveAs FileName:="C:\EPITETI CINQUE\Presentazione\RiepilogoPresentazione"

  applWord.Quit

  Set docWord = Nothing
  Set applWord = Nothing
  Set paraWord = Nothing
  Exit Sub
  errorhandler:
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help.
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things at issue here

- `On Error Resume Next` is hiding the issue from you.  Remove it
- `oSh.Ungroup.Group , msoTextBox` makes no sense, I don't know what you are trying to do there
- When you find a grouped object, iterate its members

I've refactored your code to demonstrate.

- I've removed the `Word` stuff to make the Q clearer, and just dump the text to the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G to display it in the VBA editor).  You can add it back...
- added comments on changed code, marked  `<---`
- Added indenting to make the code readable

---

```
Sub RiepilogaConWord()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSL As Slide
    Dim g As Integer '<--- move here, no point in putting it in the loop, that does nothing

    '<--- Add here to use a general error.
    ' Comment it out while debugging to expose any errors
    ' On Error GoTo errorhandler handler

    For Each oSL In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSL.Shapes
            Select Case oSh.Type
                Case Is = msoGroup
                    'On Error Resume Next  '<--- Delete this
                    'oSh.Ungroup.Group , msoTextBox '<--- Delete this
                    For g = 1 To oSh.GroupItems.Count
                        With oSh.GroupItems.Item(g) '<--- simplify
                            '<--- use g to iterate the grouped items
                            If .HasTextFrame Then '<--- more robust
                                If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                                    Debug.Print .Name & ":= " & .TextFrame.TextRange
                                End If
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next g
                    'On Error GoTo errorhandler '<--- Delete this
                Case Else
                    With oSh
                        If .HasTextFrame Then
                            If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                                Debug.Print oSh.Name & ":= " & .TextFrame.TextRange
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
            End Select
        Next
    Next
Exit Sub
errorhandler:
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen Thank you for your reply: macro works fine. I will make adjustment to have a report with Word because many items are in Greek words and with debug print this characters are not shown. Francesco